# FLTK fl_input issue

Tags: c++, linux, fltk, tiny-core-linux

I got segfault without the dummy fl_message for linux(fltk 1.3.3 Tiny core linux)

Fixed,it's a bug from 1.3.3

```
     #include <FL/Fl.H>
     #include <FL/Fl_File_Chooser.H> 
     int main(){
       //fl_message("Test");
       const char *val=fl_input("Your input");
       return Fl::run();
     }

    tc@box:~$ cd /tmp
    tc@box:/tmp$ fltk-config --compile test.cpp
    g++ -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -o 'test' 'test.cpp' /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a -lXext -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11
    tc@box:/tmp$ ./test
    tc@box:/tmp$ fltk-config --version
    1.3.1
    tc@box:/tmp$ fltk-config --compile test.cpp
    g++ -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -o 'test' 'test.cpp' /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11
    tc@box:/tmp$ ./test
    Segmentation fault
    tc@box:/tmp$ fltk-config --version
    1.3.3
    tc@box:/tmp$
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/basics.html  You need a window for your dialog

Comment: This is a test for common dialog like fl_message,fl_alert ...etc

Comment: Unlike fl_message, fl_input is not a dialog - it is a control.